# Generating a class name based on position in django template?

Tags: django

Is it possible to do the following in Django templating using template tags? I have a number of divs that get generated e.g.

**DIV-TEMPLATE.HTML**

```
<div class="id-{{ id_num }}-pos{{ id_pos }}"></div>
```

A number of other template files includes this file through the use of a template tag e.g

```
{% render_div div_id="980x250" %}
```

The template tag is set to use the first code snippet as its template. What i want to know is if its possible to have django dynamically get the position of the div (through some logic within the template tag). E.g if i had divs going vertically down the page I want the first div to have its class as

```
<div class="id-980x250-pos1"></div>
```

if this is the parameters passed `{% render_div ad_id="980x250" %}` to the render div template tag.

The second div to have

```
<div class="id-300x250-pos2"></div>
```

if this was called `{% render_div ad_id="300x250" %}` and so forth.

Logically I am trying to wrap my brain around this, there is one template that is called and I need to have it so that the pos value is generated based on its position from top (1) to bottom. I cant pass a div_pos value to the template tag because that template tag in one particular template may be used in another template whereby that position is not right.

Kind of confusing to explain but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this is possible in django, as django does not render the resulting html. (even if it would, I don't think you could guarantee the same results as in the different browsers that exist.).

The best approach to do this would probably be with some javascript. JQuery for example has a [function that returns the position of an element](http://api.jquery.com/position/).

Comment: yeh thats what i thought. Oh well i guess I guess thats the simpler way to do it as well. Thanks